# List thread safe?

Tags: c#

Can the following be considered thread safe due to the atomic operation appearance of the code.
My main concern is if the lists needs to be re-sized it becomes non-thread safe during the re-sizing.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(10);

public List<int> GetList()
{
  var temp = list;
  list = new List<int>(10);
  return temp;
}

TimerElapsed(int number)
{
  list.Add(number);
}
```

Comment: No, it's not thread safe. Even in the limited code you're showing, you could theoretically return `list` while it's being added to, and something outside could try to use it.

Comment: Afaik no generic members are ever threadsafe.

Comment: For nearly all types in the .NET Framework thread-safety is documented  in the MSDN. Please check the documentation first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither your code nor the `List<T>` are thread-safe.

The list isn't thread-safe according to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Your code is not thread safe because it lacks synchronization.

Consider two threads calling `GetList` concurrently. Let's say the first thread gets pre-empted right after setting up the `temp`. Now the second thread sets the `temp` of its own, replaces the `list`, and lets the `GetList` function run to completion. When the first thread gets to continue, it would return the same `list` that the second thread has just returned.

But that's not all! If a third thread has called `TimerElapsed` after the second thread has completed but before the first thread has completed, it would place a value in a list that is about to be overwritten without a trace. So not only would multiple threads return the same data, but also some of your data will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

No. `List<T>` is explicitly [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *not* to be thread-safe:

> It is safe to perform multiple read operations on a List, but issues can occur if the collection is modified while it’s being read. To ensure thread safety, lock the collection during a read or write operation. To enable a collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization. For collections with built-in synchronization, see the classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. For an inherently thread–safe alternative, see the ImmutableList class.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not ThreadSafe.

Try using members of the `System.Collections.Concurrent` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, a `List<T>` is not thread safe.  You can look at alternatives in the `Concurrent` namespace, possibly using the [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or there is an article here by [Dean Chalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328848/dean-chalk) [`Fast Parallel ConcurrentList<T> Implementation`](http://deanchalk.com/2010/10/07/c-fast-parallel-concurrentlistt-implementation/).

Answer (score 0):

It is not thread safe since there can be a context switch between the first line of the GetList method which transfers to TimerElapsed method. This will create inconsistent result on different scenarions. Also as other users already mentioned the List class is not thread safe and you should use the System.Collections.Concurrent equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

It is thread safe for reading only, not for writing.